# Match a string into a variable containing an object with many properties

Tags: powershell

I would ask about a way to match in powershell a string into a variable containing an object with many properties.

The variable are in this form:

```
$a = object -> property1 -> value1
            ->     "      -> value2
            -> property2 -> value3
```

I would match a string  into every value1,2,3 an so on of the object.

Many thanks.

**EDIT:**

For help you understand i need a things like this without indicate a property

```
Where-Object -property Property1 -eq "test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your object properties are value types, you can convert the object to CSV, and match that string:

```
$object = [PSCustomObject]@{
Property1 = 'Value1'
Property2 = 'Value2'
Property3 = 'Value3'
}

$String = '"Value1","Value2","Value3"'

$string -eq  ($object | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[1]
True
```

Comment: Tecnichally the value can be everything, a string, a value or and object

Comment: It can be, but if a property is an array or collection your going to get type information, not values.